# C++ Store multi-sized arrays in a variable

Tags: c++, vector, struct, cell-array

I am trying to store a cell-like structure in C++, where its elements can have arrays of different lengths like the following example:

```
myMultiSizedArray = { 
      { 1, 2, 4 },
      { 3, 5, 6, 7 },
      { 7, 8, 9, 10 },
      { 1, 3 },
      { 4, 5, 8 },
      { 9, 10 } 
      { 5 } }
```

I am thinking of using a vector in a `struct` such as the following:

```
struct f
{
    std::vector<int> elements;
};

std::vector<f> myMultiSizedArray;
```

I would appreciate it if the community could give me their feedback. Are there better, more efficient approaches? Does C++ provide a means for this? Thank you

Comment: Why the struct f? just use vector<vector<int>>  myMultiSizedArray

Comment: ... or use a type alias if you use `vector<int>` in many places: `using my_vec = std::vector<int>; std::vector<my_vec> v;`

Comment: stack overflow isn't a site for code reivews.   You need to ask a specific technical question about a specific problem you are having and provide the code to reproduce that problem.  "better" and "more efficient" are too vague to get a specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by other users as comment, you could use a vector inside another vector as in piece of code below:

---

```
using namespace std;
vector<vector<int>> myMultiSizedArray;

myMultiSizedArray.push_back({ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
myMultiSizedArray.push_back({ 6, 5, 200, 3, 2, 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

use "vector< vector< int > >" is better